# Modifying __class__ attributes and PyQt signals for building a state machine

Tags: python, class, inheritance, pyqt, signals

I am building a simple state machine, which manipulates the `__class__` attribute to identify which state we are in. This follows recipe 8.19 in "Python Cookbook, D. Beazley". The problem is when I use this recipe with `PyQt` signals, the state machine is not able to track in which `__class__` it belongs.

Here is a simplification of the state machine `Interface` I am writing:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class Interface:
    def __init__(self):
        self.new_state(DisabledState)

    def enable(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def disable(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def new_state(self, newstate):
        self.__class__ = newstate


class EnabledState(Interface):
    def enable(self):
        print('enable/enabled state')

    def disable(self):
        print('disable/enabled state')
        self.new_state(DisabledState)


class DisabledState(Interface):
    def enable(self):
        print('enable/disabled state')
        self.new_state(EnabledState)

    def disable(self):
        print('disable/disabled state')
```

When I enable then disable this state machine as so:

```
class Thread(QtCore.QObject):
enable = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
disable = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.interface = Interface()
    self.enable.connect(self.interface.enable)
    self.disable.connect(self.interface.disable)

myThread = Thread()
app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
myThread.enable.emit()
myThread.disable.emit()
app.exec_()
```

In this code above, I first enable the disabled interface and move to enabled state. Then from enabled state I disable the interface, so the expected output is:

```
# enable/disabled state
# disable/enabled state
```

However, I get the following where it looks like `interface` never went to `enabled` state.

```
# enable/disabled state
# disable/disabled state
```

Can anyone explain to me what is happening here?

**P.S.**
The book describes another recipe which does not require modification of the `__class__` attribute and no inheritance. That recipe does indeed give the correct output...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass `self.interface.enable` to `.connect()`, it references `DisabledState.enable`, so it will always behave like it is disabled. To fix this, you could use `lambda: self.interface.enable()`, and similar for `disable`.